# Node.js for real time licensing of Desktop application

Tags: node.js, licensing

My company sells a desktop application (written in C) which we license by locking our software to various parts of the users hardware. This has been cumbersome over the years given that some parts of a windows machines' id often change. I am hoping to change that with node.js but need some direction. Here is the outline of what I am trying to do:

1. Client starts my application on his desktop.
2. Desktop application sends data (presumably a hash of a license code and maybe the users email address or other data) to the server to confirm the user is authorized.
3. Server responds with another hash indicating the license is OK or not OK.
4. Session is established between client(desktop app) and server that warns the user if the license is attempted to be used on another machine.

How can the Desktop app (Client) and the node Server establish a session that can be interrupted if the user attempts to start my application from a second machine with the same license code? I have searched for something similar on npm or elsewhere to give me some direction without any luck. I have seen applications that will warn you on Machine A if you attempt to start up with Machine B (generally, a warning that asks the user if he wants to logoff to allow Machine B to gain access to the license).

Answer (score 0):

You will need a persistent connection from your server to Machine A. Basically some way to push messages, in real time, to your clients. A straightforward solution for a C client might be a TCP connection, handled by Node's [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) library. Node also has [UDP](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html). MQTT or WebSockets are other "push" message options too.

When Machine B attempts to sign into the server, the server can send a message to Machine A asking for logout. You could hold the response to Machine B to wait for logout by Machine A, or just tell Machine B to try again later (which might be nice if Machine A is offline and won't ever get the message).

The node server would have to maintain access to the licenses, what licenses are in use, and what socket connections are tied to which licenses.